# Why are there new products using "Passive" 24VDC PoE rather that standard PoE (802.3af/802.3at)?

Tags: networking

I've spent a few hours trying to fill my Amazon cart with networking goodies for a remote building on my property: Ubiquiti NanoLoco wireless bridge, outdoor high gain AP, PoE 8 port switch and IP camera. I thought this would be fun, but the differences in PoE/"PoE" are maddening!

For example, Ubuiquiti NanoStation AC (model Loco5AC) uses 24V passive POE - Why?
Another, TP-Link outdoor AP (Model N300) also uses "passive" PoE. These are current generation products, why are manufacturers not using the standard PoE? It defeats the purpose if you need to have PoE injectors all over the place for special "passive" PoE.

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cheaper for a wide variety of reasons to do proprietary bare bones POE instead of standard POE. Simpler circuits, no interop testing, no interop-related tech support. Most consumers don't know the difference, so there's very little consumer demand for standard POE.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I imagine that if you get into pro or even Pro-Sumer grade this problem becomes less of a thing?